# Is there a way to check if a field in a tab has changed value?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have several tabs on a form and several fields per tab. I wish to execute a procedure if one or more fields in only a particular tab is changed.

To elaborate, on a subform `SubForm` are a date field `Date1` and several tabs, one of which is `Tab2`. On `Tab2` are several fields including a date field `Date2`. What I want to do is copy the value of `Date1` on `Date2` IF `Date2` has been left blank AND at least one of the fields in `Tab2` has changed value, ie, the user has typed in data. I'm thinking like an OnDirty event, only that I need to trigger it not when the whole form becomes Dirty but only when those fields in the particular tab gets Dirty.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the fields in the tab `Tab2` by tagging it with an asterisk `"*"`. Then I checked if there are changes made in the tagged fields by calling a form BeforeUpdate event.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim ctl As Control
Dim myForm As Form
Set myForm = Forms!frm_MainForm!subfrm_subForm.Form

For Each ctl In myForm
    If InStr(1, ctl.Tag, "*") <> 0 Then
        If ctl.Value <> ctl.OldValue Then
            If IsNull(myForm!Date2) Then
                myForm!Date2 = Format(myForm!Date1, "Short Date")
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```